# Math, blocks and entries

Tags: c#, math, block

I have an amount of blocks that will always be 236 bytes. And then I have some entries that need to be fitted into the blocks, these will sometimes not fit into a block perfectly so the block will be left with a few null bytes.

I am trying to work out the location be be writing the entry and what block this should be in.

```
        int blocklen = 236;//always the same

        int entryindex = 14;//example index of an entry to write
        int entrylength = 16;//this will be the same in all entries in these blocks.
        int blockindex = ((entryindex + 1) * entrylength) / blocklen;//this works and will correctly calculate the index of the block to write to.
        int offset = ((entryindex) * entrylength) % blocklen;// this is incorrect, I need it to work out the offset with in the block.
```

If my entryindex is 13 it will work out as being @ 208 in block 0, and that is right. But if it was 14 it would not fit into the first block so it should be block 1 @ 0 but instead it says block 1 at offset 224, and 224 is the offset in the first block but I need to carry it over into the next block.

Am not too good at math anyway and it's not my day so I was just wondering if any of you could help me with that line of code.

Comment: Why did you mark this question C and C#?

Comment: I was thinking that both C and C# coders could help me fix it. Sorry if that was wrong.

Comment: If the language is irrelevant I recommend using pseudocode and asking for a pseudocode answer.  C and C# are incredibly different and will cause confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the tag. I only code in C# but I assumed basic arithmetical would be the same, apart from pointers. But if they are incredibly different than that was wrong sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your blocklen is not an even multiple of 16!

14 * 16 = 224

so offset will be:

```
int entries_per_block = 14;

int offset = (entryindex * entrylength) % (entrylength * entries_per_block);
```

and blockindex should be:

```
int blockindex = (entryindex * entrylength) / (entrylength * entries_per_block);
```

Comment: Thank you, and I am aware that the block length is not a multiple so there will be null space in each block. I am actually reversing someone else's binary file and this is not how I would store the data.

Will mark you as answered when it allows me.